# How to add additional tables in DashCommerce 2 using SubSonic 2.0.3

Tags: subsonic, commerce

I've inherited an website that is base on

- DashCommerce 2
- SubSonic 2.0.3

I wish to add some customfields to the project however cannot find .tt files. Also there is not option to "run tool"

Did SubSonic 2.0.3 use .tt files? I'm assuming .tt = t4?

I don't seen any active record .dll's in the bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I need to use subcommander to generate this files. Rob's made a nice [screencast](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x])

This has created new issues as i can't seem to [install subsonic tools 2.03 from here](http://subsonictools.codeplex.com/) 
i'm Win7 , VS2008

1. Does anyone have the 2.03 sonic.exe?
2. Also, i see dashcommerce has 3 generated directories

   - Controllers
   - Models
   - Utilies

I'm not sure how to generated these different kinds of classes.